# how to add weight field on checkout page in Jigoshop Plugin

Tags: e-commerce, jigoshop

Presently when  order received e-mail is mail contains following
Subtotal:  $3,075.00
Total:    $3,075.00

Now i want something like 
Subtotal:  $3,075.00
Total:    $3,075.00
Total Weight: 122kg

Can someone give me idea that where or in which files I do edit to get the desired output
plugin URL is : http://wordpress.org/plugins/jigoshop/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a callback that you hook to `wp_mail()`. The first line of the function:

```
extract( apply_filters( 'wp_mail', compact( 'to', 'subject', 'message', 'headers', 'attachments' ) )
```

The third argument `$message` is what you want to alter. Just return an array in the callback where you merge the original with your alterations.